# Attempting to reference non-static field with non-static method results in error

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor, static

I have created a class, Obstacle, with an Obstacle constructor and a function.

```
package environment;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import environment.WorldEnvironment;

public class Obstacle {

    private String obstacleType, setObstacleType;
    private int obstacleSize, obstacleXCoord, obstacleYCoord,   setObstacleSize, setObstacleXCoord, setObstacleYCoord;

public Obstacle(String getType, int getSize, int getXCoord, int getYCoord){

    obstacleType = getType;
    obstacleSize = getSize;
    obstacleXCoord = getXCoord;
    obstacleYCoord = getYCoord;

}

public void generateObstacle(int getPlayerCurrentXCoord, int   getPlayerCurrentYCoord){//code in generateObstacle}
```

In my main method, I call generateObstacle() from a different class (note that both this class and the Obstacle class are within the same package).

```
import environment.Obstacle;

public void main(String[] args){

    spawnPlayer();

    while(runGame){

        //one example of calling some Obstacle member variables and calling generateObstacle()
        switch((playerInput.nextLine()).toUpperCase()){

            case "W": 
                if(currentXCoord + 1 == Obstacle.obstacleXCoord && Obstacle.obstacleYCoord == currentYCoord){

                    out.println("There is a " + (Obstacle.obstacleType).toLowerCase() + " where you are trying to go.");
                    printPlayerCoords();

                }
                else{

                    movePlayerForward();
                    printPlayerCoords();
                    if(spawnObstacle.nextInt(8) == 3){

                        Obstacle.generateObstacle(currentXCoord, currentYCoord);

                    }

                }
                break;
```

All

```
Obstacle.
```

variable references throw an error, saying "cannot make static reference to non-static field. It is the same with

```
Obstacle.generateObstacle(currentXCoord, currentYCoord);
```

I'm not sure why I'm being given this error, because no member variables of Obstacle are static, and the main method is not static. There are also no static fields in the generateObstacle() method itself. This is the Obstacle constructer:

```
Obstacle newObstacle = new Obstacle(setObstacleType, setObstacleSize, setObstacleXCoord, setObstacleYCoord);
```

Is there someone that can explain to me why I'm getting this error? And yes, I have looked around SO but have not found any good explanatory solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The *reference* `Obstacle` is static. It is a class name. You need an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not call  `generateObstacle()` method like this -

```
 Obstacle.generateObstacle(currentXCoord, currentYCoord);
```

Since `generateObstacle()` is a non-static method in another class.

**Solution:**
**(1)** Make the `generateObstacle()` method static and call with class name-

Obstacle.generateObstacle(currentXCoord, currentYCoord);

**(2)** Or create an instance of `Obstacle`, say `anObstacle` use it to call the method -

```
 Obstacle anObstacle = new Obstacle(...);
 anObstacle.generateObstacle(currentXCoord, currentYCoord);
```

**Note:** non-static type member of a class (that is method or variables) lives within the object of a class. That means `non-static` members only usable when an object is created. This is not true for `static` member of a class. You can access `static` member of a class without creating the instance/object of a class.

Comment: OK, this seems to fix the problem. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your main method static and turn other of your methods static if you want to call them from the main method.

> You have to have the main method static for JVM

JVM will need to call the main method as an entry point to the application without having to create an instance of the containing class.

Answer (score 1):

```
Obstacle.generateObstacle(currentXCoord, currentYCoord);
```

This is a static call to a non static method. When you reference the class name, it is a static reference. Your generateObstacle method is not static, hence the error.

Try creating an instance of the class, and then reference it.

```
Obstacle obstacle = new Obstacle(...arguments...);
obstacle.generateObstacle(currentXCoord, currentYCoord);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `generateObstacle` method is a non-static method, which means each instance of the Obstacle has its own, able to access the same instance's state (fields).

In a static context (here, the `main` method), there is no instance to call the method on. So trying to call a non-static method without actually constructing an instance makes no sense.

To take a real world analogy, it would be like to try steering a car (calling `steer` method on a particular instance of a Car class) without actually having a car.

There are two possible solutions to your problem :
- construct an instance of the Obstacle class (`Obstacle o = new Obstacle()`), then calling the `generateObstacle` method on it ;
- or make the `generateObstacle` static, if it does not depend on the state of any particular instance.

Seeing that your Obstacle class has state (fields), the first one is the only solution.